# Need help in solving the error in watch channel tokio

Tags: rust, watch, rust-tokio

```
use std::mem::{self, ManuallyDrop};

/// single producer multi consumer

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    use tokio::sync::watch;
    use tokio::time::{Duration, sleep};

    let (tx, _rx) = watch::channel("hello");
    let mut rx2 = tx.subscribe();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let res = rx2.has_changed();
            if res.is_err() {
                break;
            }
            if !res.ok().unwrap_or_else(|| true ) {
                continue;
            }
            println!("{}! ", *rx2.borrow_and_update());
        }
    });

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    for i in 0..10 {
        let val = format!("World {}!", i);
        tx.send(val.as_str()).unwrap();
    }
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
}
```

This code fails with error:

```
error[E0597]: `val` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:17
   |
27 |         let val = format!("World {}!", i);
   |             --- binding `val` declared here
28 |         tx.send(val.as_str()).unwrap();
   |                 ^^^---------
   |                 |
   |                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `val` is borrowed for `'static`
29 |     }
   |     - `val` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Can anyone help me send the message to all the consumers in the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Because of this line, the element type of the channel is inferred to be `&str`:

```
let (tx, _rx) = watch::channel("hello");
```

Then, you send `val.as_str()` which returns a `&str` that borrows from `val`, but `val` is going to be destroyed when the loop iteration ends.

Just send owned values (`String`) instead of borrowed ones.  You can do this by sending `val` instead of `val.as_str()`.  You will also have to send `"hello".to_owned()` instead of `"hello"` to make the types match.

Comment: is there no way we can send &str ?

Comment: @ShivamVarshney Not in your code, because the `Receiver` gets sent to a new task. A future that is used to spawn a new task must have `'static` lifetime, which means it cannot borrow anything with a shorter lifetime than `'static`. You would also need to ensure that the owned value outlives the reference; your current code does not do this.